# PHP - Create file download with strip_tag

Tags: php

This is the code I am using:

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fakeFileName");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
fpassthru($fp)
```

The actual file residing on the server has HTML content as well, so would like to use `strip_tags()`, but it doesn't seem to work here. Tried using `file_get_contents` + `strip_tags()` but that gives a failed download.

I understand this is something to do with streams. Not sure which function would help me here to just get rid of the html tags in the file and give a plain text download.

Comment: You may want to read what strip_tags actually does, you cannot use it before you have the actual content you want to strip of tags. What happens if you just use `file_get_contents($fakeFileName)`, do you get contents then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
$filedata = file_get_contents($file) ; // Get file content as string 
$filedata = strip_tags($filedata) ; // strip tag in the string 

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream") ;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fakeFileName") ;
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($filedata)) ; // final string size
echo $filedata ; // outputs content
exit(0) ; // stop script
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. Note to OP: this has the added downside of not streaming the file, so memory limits can be hit, but I'm not sure if with PHP that can really be avoided. Better solution would be performing strip_tags on the file beforehand, assuming the file contents can be changed.